# Why do we need to use broadcast listener to list Wi-Fi APs?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifi

I would like to know why do we need to use broadcast listeners if I am developing an application to list all the Wi-Fi in my phone's range?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a broadcast receiver to list all the local wifi signals. Try this code within your activity,

```
public Lit<ScanResult> getNetworks() {
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    return manager.getScanResults();
}
```

Each ScanResult object contains information above each network. Here's what's in it, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html

You'll also need this permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```